# Run .command with input at runtime

Tags: terminal, command-line

I need to run a .command file with input at runtime, but I want to run via double click, not from terminal.

I have a file `adbInstall.command` file with this code

```
adb install /Directory/$1.apk
```

From terminal, I can do `adbInstall.command fileName` and it will properly run `adb install /Directory/fileName.apk`

How can I input `fileName` whilst double clicking on adbInstall.command instead of running it from terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **Automator.app**:

1. Open **Automator** and create a new **Work Flow**
2. Go to **Actions / Library / Text**
3. Choose *Ask for Text* and enable the *Require an answer* checkbox.
4. Go to **Library / Utilities**
5. Choose *Run Shell Script*
6. Select **as arguments** on the *pass input:* drop down.
7. Type `adb install /Directory/$1.apk` as the actual script.
8. Save as **Application**.

Now you'll have a clicable file which will ask for the parameter for the script.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In case somebody else runs across it, I had a bash profile setup, so I also had to add `source ~/.bash_profile` to the script before the `adb` line.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your .command with something such as:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]
then
  thefile=$1
else  
  read -p 'enter filename: ' thefile
fi
  echo "filename is:" $thefile

adb install /Directory/$thefile.apk

echo "done."
```